# How can I run multiple Sidekiq Workers on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, worker

I have multiple workers, each of them seperated based on WorkerClass 
Specified queues, concurrency etc. They are triggerin via cron jobs.

```
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q worker1 -c 5 -e production
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q worker2 -c 5 -e production
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q worker3 -c 5 -e production
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q worker4 -c 5 -e production
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q worker5 -c 5 -e production
```

So, I need to start all of them on EC2 instance, and restart them after next deploy.
Can I use capistrano to do this? or any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: here is some samples: http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/07/16/sidekiq-and-upstart/ 
http://requiremind.com/deploying-a-rails-app-on-your-own-server-the-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like [God](http://godrb.com/), [upstart](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart), or [runit](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/runit) to keep your sidekiq processes up and running.